# jQuery, get the outer function selector

Tags: jquery, function

How can i get the `$(this)` in the `setTimeout` to get the hover function's selector in the case below `img`.

```
$("img").hover(function(){
window.setTimeout(function() {  
    $(this).addClass("hovering"); // add class .hovering to the exact img being hovered
}, 500);  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `this` in some other variable.

```
$("img").hover(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    window.setTimeout(function() {  
        $this.addClass("hovering"); // add class .hovering to the exact img being hovered
    }, 500);  
});
```

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa: Stop bashing my improper terminology with rhetorical questions! :)